# How can make the responsive path which it inside svg

Tags: html, css, svg, height, width

I have here svg design, I put it inside a div also this div has navbar and some elements , when the screen is small every thing is okay, but when I increase the screen size the height of svg increases also and be like height:100% although I didn't customize the height and width of the svg, I just customized the viewbox , and it is problem because it comes over the other elements and I can not  click or  hover the buttons, and when I customize for example the width:100%; and height:400px; for the svg , the path inside it becomes small and not responsive
So what should i do in this case?
I want the width of svg become 100% and the height is 400px or samller, also i want the shape(path) inside it becomes responsive and its width always  100%

Note: I made the border of svg visible to understant how the height becomes when the screen is large

["SIMPLE LANDING PAGE" https://codepen.io/aseelkhanfar19/pen/OJgaNEy][1]

Comment: If you need to be able to click the button under the svg element you can add `pointer-events: none` to the svg

Comment: Thankkkk yooouuu , it worked 